# Function problems and errors

Tags: vb.net

I was having trouble with my school assignment. I have to calculate the sub total in a sub procedure (works) sales tax in a function. the sub procedure works but I'm having all kinds trouble with the function. Calling the sub procedure SubTotal() doesn't return a value, getting the value from lblSubtotal gives System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'. any tips and pointers would be much appreciated, thanks.

**Code**

```
Public Class frmMain

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub ClearLables(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles radChocolate.CheckedChanged, radCappuccino.CheckedChanged,
    radFilled.CheckedChanged, radGlazed.CheckedChanged, radNone.CheckedChanged,
    radRegular.CheckedChanged, radSugar.CheckedChanged
    ' Clears labels
    lblSalesTax.Text = String.Empty
    lblSubtotal.Text = String.Empty
    lblTotalDue.Text = String.Empty

End Sub

Public Sub CalculateSubtotal()
    Dim decSubtotal As Decimal = 0

    If radGlazed.Checked Then
        decSubtotal += 1.05
    ElseIf radSugar.Checked Then
        decSubtotal += 1.05
    ElseIf radChocolate.Checked Then
        decSubtotal += 1.25
    ElseIf radFilled.Checked Then
        decSubtotal += 1.5
    End If

    If radNone.Checked Then
        decSubtotal = 0
    ElseIf radRegular.Checked Then
        decSubtotal += 1.5
    ElseIf radCappuccino.Checked Then
        decSubtotal += 2.75
    End If

    lblSubtotal.Text = decSubtotal.ToString("C2")

End Sub
Public Function SalesTax() As Decimal

    Const decTaxRate As Decimal = 0.06
    Dim decSalesTax As Decimal
    Dim decSubtotal = Decimal.Parse(lblSubtotal.Text)

    decSalesTax = decSubtotal * decTaxRate

    Return decSalesTax

End Function

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

    CalculateSubtotal()
    lblSalesTax.Text = SalesTax().ToString("C2")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: your code doesn't include the `subTotal` method :) ?

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is that the value in the `Label` is formatted as currency but you don't specify that when you try to parse it back.  `Decimal.Parse` allows you to specify how the input can be formatted and, if you don't specify currency then currency is invalid.  You should do some reading on `Decimal.Parse` and the like to learn how to specify allowable formats.

That's not really the "proper" solution to the problem though.  The thing is, a `Label` is for the purpose of data DISPLAY, not data STORAGE.  There's no good reason to ever be getting data from a `Label`.  The user can't input anything into a `Label` so if there's data there then you must have put it there from somewhere.  If you need that data, you should be getting it from that original somewhere, NOT from the `Label`.

In this case, you have a `Decimal` value in the `decSubtotal` variable and that is the source for the `Label`.  When you need that data, you should be getting it from that same variable, NOT from the `Label`.  That means that that variable needs to be declared at the class level rather than at the method level, i.e. a member rather than a local.  Because that variable is type `Decimal`, there's no parsing required and you can simply use it as is.